# Is it possible to create a Component abstraction on Angular 2?

Tags: angular, architecture, abstraction

I want to create a AbstractComponent with initial behavior while being able to override it on child when needed, is it possible? Is it a good practice?

Should look more or less like that:

```
export abstract class AbstractComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(authService: AuthService, router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (authService.userNotLoggedInAnymore()) {
      router.navigate(['Login']);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you run into issues with this approach?

Comment: I am wondering how can I specify providers for Authservice and Router for exemple since I cant use the @Component annotation, mainly because it has no template.. It makes me wonder if angular 2 is designed to this purpouse

Comment: I guess you would specify such providers in `bootstrap()` anyway, not on each component. If you want a singleton, you must only pass it in `bootstrap()` otherwise a new instance is created for each component.

Comment: Oh really? Thats new for me :O

Comment: Only providers where you actually want a new instance for each component should be listed in `@Component(providers: [])`.

Comment: Yea, misunderstood the docs, thanks

Comment: Does this all answer your question(s)? Or are still parts not yet addressed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100511/discussion-between-marcos-j-c-kichel-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, just extend that class with the real `@Component` and call `super()` in the methods you override, like ngOnInit. And you also have to override the constructor with at least the same or more dependencies in the parent and pass them with `super()` too.

Comment: how about the template, can get nested too with the parent abstract component?

Comment: Component inheritance does not cover templates and styles.

Comment: I'm getting error when building Angular 4 app with --aot: "ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class [MyComponent] in [file]!  Add [MyComponent] to the NgModule to fix it." Anyone has workaround for this?

Comment: Having the same issue as @Algis - anyone end up finding a fix for that?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you can also do **without the constructor parameters** in the abstract class at all and declare the services with the **@Inject** decorator, then you don´t need to touch the constructor of the inheriting class and call the super(...)-method there:

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class AbstractComponent implements OnInit {

  @Inject(AuthService) private authService: AuthService;
  @Inject(Router) private router: Router;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (authService.userNotLoggedInAnymore()) {
      router.navigate(['Login']);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little late but I found a workaround for those who are getting

```
ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class [MyComponent] in [file]!
Add [MyComponent] to the NgModule to fix it.
```

when building with AOT.
When adding the component to the `declaration` section, try cast it with `<any>` e.g. `<any>MyComponent`.
This doesn't sound so clean but at least it works for me.
If anyone happens to find a better solution, please kindly share :)

Comment: Thanks for the call out! Thought this was a no go, until I saw your comment. Thanks!