# How to extend a component?

Tags: angular

I have a component `A` which I want to reuse many times, but with additional properties and methods. How can I extend component `B` with it? Will `A` rewrite template? Or should I use directive? Is it even possible?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752288/is-it-possible-to-create-a-component-abstraction-on-angular-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a sample here with inheritance.

```js
        export class Clock {

            time:string;
            offset:number;

            constructor(offset){
                this.offset = offset;
            }

            ngOnInit(){
                this.time = moment.utc().add(this.offset,'h');
                setInterval(() => {
                    this.time = moment.utc().add(this.offset,'h');
                },1000);
            }
        }

        //component1
        @Component({
            selector: 'new-york',
            templateUrl: './clock.html'
        })

        export class NewYork extends Clock{
            city = 'New York';

            constructor(){
                super(-5);
            }
        }

        //component2
        @Component({
            selector: 'london',
            templateUrl: './clock.html'

        })

        export class London extends Clock{
            city = 'London';

            constructor(){
                super(0);
            }
        }
```

I am reusing the Clock class in 3 different components.

Comment: This is perfect! Also, maybe do you know how to use angular2 DI inside clock component? Let's say I want to inject `someService` to class and then extend component with it. Right now I'm injecting service separately for every component which is not very enjoyable, but it works.